# zsh: no matches found: protobuf==3.20.* on macos

Tags: python, macos, pip, zsh

```
MacBook-Air ~ % pip install protobuf==3.20.*
zsh: no matches found: protobuf==3.20.*



TypeError: Descriptors cannot not be created directly.
If this call came from a _pb2.py file, your generated code is out of date and must be regenerated with protoc >= 3.19.0.
If you cannot immediately regenerate your protos, some other possible workarounds are:
 1. Downgrade the protobuf package to 3.20.x or lower.
 2. Set PROTOCOL_BUFFERS_PYTHON_IMPLEMENTATION=python (but this will use pure-Python parsing and will be much slower).
```

Comment: Personally I used PROTOCOL_BUFFERS_PYTHON_IMPLEMENTATION=python at the cost of some performance

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 4):

`protobuf==3.20.*`, since it contains the metacharacter `*` and is not quoted, is interpreted by Zsh as a glob to expand.

Unlike `bash`, a glob that doesn't match anything produces an error, rather than producing the literal string as an argument to `pip install`.

Anything that you don't intend for the shell to process should be quoted.

```
pip install 'protobuf==3.20.*'
```

Comment: Or escaped `pip install protobuf==3.20.\*`

Comment: Which type of quoting/escaping you use doesn't matter; you just need to tell the shell you mean it literally. You could also do things like `3.20.'*'` or `3.20".*"` I generally use single quotes around anything I intend as literal.